# How to fix an "field has incomplete type" error when using a forward declaration

Tags: c++, incomplete-type

This code throws the compiler error `error: field ‘fTarget’ has incomplete type` as noted in the comments.   Why is this happening?  I'm only assigning that field and not doing any operations that would need to know what is inside... or am I?   Maybe it can't figure out the copy constructor?

```
class FSRVertex;  //fwd

class FSREdge
 {
 public:
    char fC;
    FSRVertex fTarget;   //compiler error
    FSREdge(char c, FSRVertex target) : fC(c), fTarget(target) {}  //compiler error
};


class FSRVertex {
public:
    boost::unordered_map<char, FSREdge> fOutEdges;
    FSRVertex() : fOutEdges() {}
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have an FSRVertex object as a member of your class, the compiler needs to know its size, and so needs to see its full definition.

Either provide the full definition for your class, or you can store a pointer (preferably smart pointer) to a dynamically allocated copy of the object performed in the constructor. You will need to move the constructor body outside the class to a place where the full definition is provided. This approach is less efficient at run-time.

Comment: A reference would be fine too.

Comment: @black reference won't be fine in general as will change ownership.

Comment: @Slava That's another thing. I just wanted to point out that a reference would solve that as well, not whether is advisable to do so or not.

Comment: @black technically yes that would fix issue with forward declaration. But for this specific example using reference would not be a good answer IMHO

Comment: I would just like to add that you can achieve the same goal via templates. The first example (rextester.com/TLPEJW28982) declares A as a global class and defines it after the class template definition. As an advantage, you don't have to worry about where you define struct A and you avoid coupling. The second example (rextester.com/PJCD69132) considers A as a nested struct of B. The reason this compiles and runs fine is because of the two-phase lookup that occurs when instantiating a template. For more details, please refer to C++ Templates: The Complete Guide, 10.3.1 Two-Phase Lookup.

Answer (score 1):

You could always make `FSRVertex` a template parameter of `FSREdge`. Then the compiler has to wait with calculating the size of `FSREdge` until specialization and not knowing the size of `FSRVertex` is not an issue anymore. It is a bit goofy, but it does what you want and there is no runtime overhead:

```
class FSRVertex; // fwd

template <class FSRVertex_Forward = FSRVertex> // make fwd the default type
class FSREdge_ {
public:
    char fC;
    FSRVertex_Forward fTarget;

    FSREdge_(char c, FSRVertex_Forward target)
        :fC(c), fTarget(target)
    {}

    FSREdge_(const FSREdge_ &other) // std::map requires copy ctor
        :fC(other.fC), fTarget(other.fTarget)
    {}

    FSREdge_() // std::map requires default ctor
    {}
};

typedef FSREdge_<> FSREdge; // so that you don't have to carry the brackets everywhere

class FSRVertex {
public:
    std::map<char, FSREdge> fOutEdges;
    FSRVertex()
        :fOutEdges()
    {}
};
```

You can see this work on [ideone](http://ideone.com/18k19l).

Answer (score -4):

This error means the forward declaration is insufficient, the way you're using that type.

You can't fix it.

Comment: What do you mean by it can't be fixed?

Comment: @NeilKirk: Forward declarations cannot be employed for a type for which a size must be known. The forward declaration cannot be fixed.

Comment: @Neil Well at least you can rest easy now that three other people have also failed to understand this basic English.

Comment: @NeilKirk: You cannot make the forward declaration work. I do not know how to make this any clearer for you.

Comment: You are taking the question too literally. He wanted some workarounds, I gave some.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Never said you shouldn't!